# Learning Python: Changing value in list based on condition

Tags: python

Sorry for the very basic question, but this is actually a 2-part question:

1. Given a list, I need to replace the values of '?' with 'i' and the 'x' with an integer, 10. The list does not always have the same number of elements, so I need a loop that permits me to do this.

   ```
   a = ['1', '7', '?', '8', '5', 'x']
   ```
2. How do I grab the index of where the value is equal to '?'. It'd be nice if this show me how I could grab all the index and values in a list as well.

Comment: When you say "keys and values", do you actually mean indices and values? Key/value pairs are used with dicts, not lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a function for it and use `map()` to call it on every element:

```
def _replaceitem(x):
    if x == '?':
        return 'i'
    elif x == 'x':
       return 10
    else:
        return x

a = map(_replaceitem, a)
```

Note that this creates a new list. If the list is too big or you don't want this for some other reason, you can use `for i in xrange(len(a)):` and then update `a[i]` if necessary.

To get `(index, value)` pairs from a list, use [`enumerate(a)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) which returns an iterator yielding such pairs.

To get the first index where the list contains a given value, use [`a.index('?')`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

Answer (score 5):

Only because no one's mentioned it yet, here's my favourite non-for-loop idiom for performing replacements like this:

```
>>> a = ['1', '7', '?', '8', '5', 'x']
>>> reps = {'?': 'i', 'x': 10}
>>> b = [reps.get(x,x) for x in a]
>>> b
['1', '7', 'i', '8', '5', 10]
```

The [.get()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method is incredibly useful, and scales up better than an if/elif chain.

Answer (score 4):

For 1:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == '?':
        a[i] = 'i'
    elif a[i] == 'x':
        a[i] = 10
```

For 2, what do you mean by "key"? If you mean index:

```
index = a.index('?')
```

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading the [Built-in Types section of the Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).  I think that you are looking for `list.index`.

Answer (score 2):

it is function called 'index':

```
>>> a = ['1', '7', '?', '8', '5', 'x']
>>> a.index('?')
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now use lambda

```
# replace occurrences of ?
a = map(lambda x: i if x == '?' else x, a)
# replace occurrences of x
a = list(map(lambda x: 10 if x == 'x' else x, a))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['1', '7', '?', '8', '5', 'x']
for index, item in enumerate(a):
    if item == "?":
       a[index] = "i"
    elif item == "x":
       a[index = 10

print a
```