# why does my for loop not edit the global list I and looping through and editing?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

There is probably a matching question out there. I have a globally defined list and I am trying to iterate through the list and edit certain elements by using specific if statements. My problem is that when I print the list before the loop and when I print the list afterwards they are still the same.

I've considered using enumerate to manually edit list["enumerated number"] using the numbers connected to the element but this seems clumsy.

```
print(list)
for el in list:
    print(el)
    if el < 1:
        el = 0
    elif el > 1:
        el = 2
print(list)
```

I am hoping to get an output that is the top list edited according to the if statements.

Comment: You haven't done anything to change the list.  All you've done is to change, then reuse, your loop index.

Comment: Find the different and best solution for your problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470056/learning-python-changing-value-in-list-based-on-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that Python variables are just names. Each pass through the loop, `el` is initially set to be a name for whatever is at the next list index. If the next value was 3, for example, the computer will now replace `el` with 3 whenever it occurs.

But when you have a statement like `el = 2`, all you are doing is telling the computer that from now on, `el` is just another name for the number 2. You have not actually edited the underlying list element. In order to do this, you will need to do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i])
    if list[i] < 1:
        list[i] = 0
    elif list[i] > 1:
        list[i] = 2
```

The reason this would work is that instead of giving a name to each list element, and then giving that name to something else, you are actually changing the list elements themselves.

Answer (score 2):

As Derek Langley suggested, you can do it by indexing the list. Rather than `range(len(list))`, it's a good habit to use `enumerate(list)`

```
print(list)
for index, value in enumerate(list):
    print(value)
    if value < 1:
        list[index] = 0
    elif value > 1:
        list[index] = 2
print(list)
```

Edit: I would have added this as a comment, but I don't have enough points yet!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] < 1:
        list[i] = 0
    elif list[i] > 1:
        list[i] = 2
```

I believe the reason why your code isn't working is because you are referencing the object inside the list, and not the object's position.

Comment: I believe the reason why your code isn't working is because you are referencing the object inside the list, and not the object's position.

Comment: That comment *is* your answer.  You should put it there, instead of as a comment.  A good answer always explains the code you give, and why it should work when the original code did not.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Hi! I forgot to add it and decided to add it as a comment. My bad!

Comment: See [edit].  Comments can be deleted at will; don't lose good content!

Comment: Hi. Could you explain what you mean by that. For a nested array, you just have to use another layer of indexing (list[i][j])